# Need help on a probability calculation

Tags: probability

Following is a problem statement:

> A furniture shop has six identical steel cabinets of brand A and four
>   identical steel cabinets of brand B. Three customers buy one cabinet
>   each. Then the probability that two or more cabinets of brand A have
>   been sold is

My answer was 1/2, but it's incorrect. My initial attempt was as follows 6/10*5/9 + 6/10*5/9*4/8 = 1/2.

Comment: The value $\frac{6}{10}\times \frac{5}{9}$ represents the probability that the first and second person both buy brand $A$ and what the third person bought doesn't matter.  Meanwhile $\frac{6}{10}\times\frac{5}{9}\times\frac{4}{8}$ represents the probability that all three people bought brand $A$.  Not only do you have a bit of overlap between these two terms, you also are missing out on accounting for the cases where the first person bought brand $B$ and the other two bought brand $A$ or when the second person bought brand $B$ and the first and third persons both bought brand $A$.

Comment: This is, of course, working under the assumption that each customer buys one of the available cabinets uniformly at random.  (*if all customers went to the store to specifically buy brand $A$ then clearly the probability would be 100%*)

Answer (score 2):

What is the probability that **exactly** two cabinets sold were of type A?

There are 3 possible situations:

1. first customer buys A, second A, third buys B
2. first customer buys B, second A, third buys A
3. first customer buys A, second B, third buys A

The probability of 1. scenario is $\frac{6}{10}\cdot \frac{5}{9} \cdot \frac{4}{8}$

To determine the probability of the event that **exactly** two cabinets of type A have been bought, you have to add up the probability of all 3 scenarios, that is

$\frac{6}{10}\cdot \frac{5}{9} \cdot \frac{4}{8} + 
\frac{4}{10}\cdot \frac{6}{9} \cdot \frac{5}{8}+
\frac{6}{10}\cdot \frac{4}{9} \cdot \frac{5}{8} = \frac{1}{2}$

This is why your calculation failed.

If you add the probability that all cabinets were of type A, you get the probability you want.

$\frac{1}{2} +\frac{6}{10}\cdot \frac{5}{9} \cdot \frac{4}{8} = \frac{2}{3}$

Comment: I see that your reasoning follows that of JMoravitz. It's intuitive and confirms the 2/3 answer according to Brian Tung. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

**Basic approach.** (Assuming, as JMoravitz indicates in the comments, that each customer buys a cabinet from the available selection uniformly at random...)  There are ten cabinets: six A's and four B's.  Out of those ten, you choose three.  What expression represents the number of ways to choose three cabinets?  That's your denominator.

How many ways are there to choose three A's?  How many ways are there to choose two A's and one B?  Add those together and that's your numerator.

The probability is the numerator over the denominator.

Comment: I got 2/3 according to your reasoning. As Vlad stated earlier, I would need to compute no. of scenario/all possible scenario. Thanks.